# How to wrap List<int[]> with C++Builder 11?

Tags: android, delphi, java-native-interface, c++builder

I'm struggling to access the data returned by `camera_parameters->getSupportedPreviewFpsRange()` with C++Builder 11.

The `getSupportedPreviewFpsRange()` function is described here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#getSupportedPreviewFpsRange()

I don't have any issue with wrapping data which is not an array returned by other functions, but I could not find a way to wrap the `List<int[]>` data type.

The Delphi way to handle this seems to be:

```pascal
camera_parameters: JCamera_Parameters;
pointer: Pointer;
jobject: JObject;
list_fps_ranges: JList;
currentFpsRange, suitableFPSRange: TJavaArray<Integer>;

...

list_fps_ranges := camera_parameters.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
jobject := list_fps_ranges.get(I);
pointer := (jobject as ILocalObject).GetObjectID;

fpsRange := TJavaArray<Integer> (WrapJNIArray(pointer, TypeInfo(TJavaArray<Integer>)));
```

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to properly translate:

```pascal
fpsRange := TJavaArray<Integer> (WrapJNIArray(pointer, TypeInfo(TJavaArray<Integer>)));
```

into C++.

I tried with:

```cpp
TJavaObjectArray__1<_di_JInteger>
```

without any luck, as there is no `WrapJNIArray()` function.

How could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, I could not find a way to properly translate:
>
> ```pascal
> fpsRange := TJavaArray<Integer> (WrapJNIArray(pointer, TypeInfo(TJavaArray<Integer>)));
> ```
>
> into C++.

Try something like this:

```cpp
_di_JCamera_Parameters camera_parameters;
TJavaArray__1<int> *currentFpsRange;
TJavaArray__1<int> *suitableFPSRange;

... 

_di_JList list_fps_ranges = camera_parameters->getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
_di_JObject jobject = list_fps_ranges->get(I);

void *objID = ((_di_ILocalObject)jobject)->GetObjectID();  

// alternatively:
//
// #include <Androidapi.Helpers.hpp>
// void *objID = TAndroidHelper::JObjectToID(jobject);

TJavaArray__1<int> *fpsRange = (TJavaArray__1<int>*) WrapJNIArray(objID, __typeinfo(TJavaArray__1<int>));
```

> I tried with:
>
> ```pascal
> TJavaObjectArray__1<_di_JInteger>
> ```
>
> without any luck, as there is no `WrapJNIArray()` function.

First, `TJavaArray<Integer>` translates to `TJavaArray__1<int>`, not to `TJavaObjectArray__1<_di_JInteger>`.

Second, `WrapJNIArray()` is a helper function declared in `<Androidapi.JNIBridge.hpp>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `List<int[]` **list_fps_ranges** example you posted works fine but I'm still confused about how to use `WrapJNIArray` properly in the case of a simple `List<Integer>`

I tried to replicate your solution with the `getZoomRatios()` function which is also part of `Camera.Parameters`

The `getZoomRatios()` function returns a `List<Integer>`

```
int n_zoomratios;
void *pointer;
_di_JList list_zoomratios;
        
list_zoomratios= jcamera_parameters->getZoomRatios(); // return List<Integer>
        
_di_JObject jobject= list_zoomratios; //fishy... 
        
pointer= TAndroidHelper::JObjectToID(jobject);
TJavaArray__1<int> *zoomratios = (TJavaArray__1<int>*) WrapJNIArray(pointer, __typeinfo(TJavaArray__1<int>));
```

Unfortunately I can not figure which parameters of `list_zoomratio` should be used by `jobject`.

In the fps ranges example, the `list_preview_fps->get()` function returns a `JObject` which is attributed to `jobject` but in the case of the `list_zoomratios` there is no obvious `JObject` parameter I could use. I tried many different ways but without any success.
What is the proper way to wrap the integer array?
By the way, is there a book/document which describes these wrapping mechanisms? I could not find any information online on this subject.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved this way:

```
        int n_zoomratios;
        int i;

        void *pointer;
        _di_JList list_zoomratios;
        _di_JInteger zoomratio;

        list_zoomratios= jcamera_parameters->getZoomRatios();       // List<Integer>
        n_zoomratios=list_zoomratios->size();

        for(i=0;i<n_zoomratios;i++)
            {
            _di_JObject jobject=list_zoomratios->get(i);
            pointer= TAndroidHelper::JObjectToID(jobject);
            zoomratio = TJInteger::Wrap(pointer);

            sprintf(txt,"%d %d",i,zoomratio->intValue());
            log(txt);
            }
```

However I can not figure why I can not convert a full array with WrapJNIArray and I have to convert each element one by one instead.